# Sqlite memory management

Tags: memory, sqlite

I am using sqlite browser to run some queries. In case of queries which return huge data, sqlite consumes large amount of RAM and does not free it until the browser is closed / killed. Is there a way to free memory without closing the process. Is this configurable?

Comment: This is how dynamic memory management works in SQLLITE. The memory would be freed when required.

Comment: but it's taking up RAM from my system.

Comment: It would release when required, dont worry about it. It takes RAM to cache objects and pages to avoid I/O

Comment: @Akshay why do you worry about that? Do you prefer your RAM unused? If it releases it when something else needs it you're fine.

Comment: @TomV Just to update, I also tried to analyze the memory usage by building a java application. I created an exe from my java application. When I run query from this application, the exe also starts consuming memory when queries are run and blocks it (does not release it)

Comment: @TomV I need my process to free up RAM because I am working on optimisation of the process.

Comment: Do you need your java process to free up RAM or sqlite?

Comment: I was just checking how much memory is taken, by trying different routes to run query. Answer to your question: I need java process to free memory